# Criar Botao usando document.createElement()

Tags: javascript, button

Preciso muito de uma ajuda, desde ja agradeco.
Preciso criar esta função:

```
<input type="button" value="Refresh Page" onClick="history.go(0)">
```

Porem ela deve ser criada usando o metodo document.createElement() e não estou conseguindo, ja tentei de varias maneiras mas sempre termino com uma caixa de input text vazia que nao serve pra nada e o botao nem mesmo aparece.
Caso nao seja possivel criar este botao, um texto escrito *AGAIN* clicavel para refresh tambem serve.Tentei fazer e a pagina fica em reload eterno antes mesmo de ser carregada.  Aproveitando ja a pergunta, caso eu mude o `history.go(0)` para `history.go(-1)` ele volta para a pagina anterior?  Muito obrigado desde ja.
Para link

```
var ae = document.createElement('a');
var eText = document.createTextNode("AGAIN");
ae.appendChild(eText);
ae.title = "AGAIN";
ae.href = window.location.reload();
document.body.appendChild(ae);
```

Para Botao

```
    var batsu = document.createElement("input");  
    batsu.setAttribute('type', 'button');  
    batsu.setAttribute('valeu', 'AGAIN');  
    batsu.setAttribute('onClick', 'history.go(0)');  
    document.body.appendChild(batsu);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para criar um botão com `document.createElement`, siga o exemplo:

***Button***

```js
function createButton()
{
     var btn = document.createElement('BUTTON');
     var lbl = document.createTextNode("CLICK ME");        
     btn.appendChild(lbl);   
     btn.onclick = function()
     {
        window.history.go(0);
     }
     document.body.appendChild(btn);    
}

createButton();
```

***input type button***

```js
var batsu = document.createElement("input");  
    batsu.type = 'button';  
    batsu.value = 'AGAIN';  
    batsu.onclick = function() { window.history.go(0); };  
    document.body.appendChild(batsu);
```

***Referencias***

- [Document.createElement()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)
- [HTML DOM createTextNode() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_createtextnode.asp)
- [HTML DOM appendChild() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp)

Comment: Exatamente o que eu estava precisando, muito obrigado Virgilio e Lucas

Comment: @Kappa eu fiz do seu jeito tinha problema no código e agora também funciona dá uma olhada

Comment: INCRIVEL, eu estava quebrando a cabeca a horas nisso, muito obrigado mesmo

Answer (score -4):

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello, World!");
}
```

}

.button {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Defina o estilo da animação */
@keyframes exemplo {
0% {transform: scale(1);}
50% {transform: scale(1.2);}
100% {transform: scale(1);}
}

/* Aplicar o estilo ao elemento que será animado */
#elementoAnimado {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background-color: blue;
animation-name: exemplo;
animation-duration: 2s; /* Duração da animação em segundos */
animation-play-state: paused; /* Pausar a animação inicialmente */
}

Clique em mim

Clique para animar

function animarElemento() {
  var elemento = document.getElementById("elementoAnimado");
  elemento.style.animationPlayState = "running"; // Iniciar a animação
}